# Android: Read any specific image from sd card and display it as bitmap

Tags: android, mediastore

I have retrieved the name of the very first image saved in the media on the sdcard of the emulator.
Now I want to display the image corresponding to it.. How can I do this ?

Here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);


  imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
  String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,

    };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Log.i("URI", images.toString());

            // Make the query.
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,         // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // Selection arguments (none)
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID          // Ordering
            );

    Log.i("ListingImages"," query count="+cur.getCount());

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String bucket;
        String date;
        String name;


        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

        int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE);


            // Get the field values
            bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
            date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
            name = cur.getString(nameColumn);



            // Do something with the values.
            Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + bucket 
                   + "  name_taken=" + name);

    }


 }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: [Visit the link for code to get images from specific path...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14230278/2710009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as for getting image path from MediaStore and then set it to ImageView:

```
//YOUR CODE HERE...
String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
             MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, // add DATA column
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,

    };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Log.i("URI", images.toString());

            // Make the query.
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,         // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // Selection arguments (none)
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID          // Ordering
            );

    Log.i("ListingImages"," query count="+cur.getCount());

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String bucket;
        String date;
        String name;


        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

        int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE);


            // Get the field values
            bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
            date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
            name = cur.getString(nameColumn);
          int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
          String picPath = cur.getString(columnIndex);

             imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath));
            // Do something with the values.
            Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + bucket 
                   + "  name_taken=" + name);

    }


 }
```

Comment: see my edit just change `int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DATA);` to `int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);`

Comment: checked...I just cant figure where the problem is..Its crashing

Comment: @Saaram : now code is  right you can check log why it's crashing

Comment: yes remove `MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,` column from everywhere. where you find this column name?

Comment: ok I got the image... But after I removed all the three columns !

Comment: Now can you tell me how to get each and every detail of this file/image ?

Comment: @Saaram :see http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/loading-listview-with-sdcard-thumbnail-images-and-displaying-its-title-size-width-and-height-by-merging-cursors-using-matrixcursor/ tutorial for getting more column from MediaStore maybe helpful for u

Comment: @Saaram : also see http://code.google.com/codesearch#7ScI3TUbNJo/trunk/jvs/src/jvs/vfs/opt/media/MediaUtils.java&q=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN&ct=rc&cd=1 in this class he is querying all calum from MediaStore.Images.Media.